# Como melhorar a semântica das perguntas do site?

Tags: debate, edição

Acredito que deveríamos nos empenhar em "profissionalizar" um pouco o site, não para enrijecer o processo ou sermos carrascos, a ponto de, sair editando todas as perguntas que são feitas. Mas, para fins de qualidade da língua culta escrita que "estamos administrando o site", no nosso caso a língua portuguesa-brasileira.

**Por exemplo, vejo perguntas no site do tipo:**

1. Verificar registro, se não existir, inserir no BD (grandes volumes)
2. Armazenar dados globais em um aplicativo

**Ao invés de:**

1. Como manipular grandes volumes de dados em um banco de dados?
2. Qual a melhor forma e como implementar o armazenamento de dados globais em um aplicativo? (O interessante dessa é que o próprio autor faz essa pergunta dentro da descrição, mas no título está outra coisa)

As próprias dúvidas, acredito que de muitos usuários do site pesquisadas no `SOen` começam com "*How...*", ou seja, "Como fazer? Qual melhor maneira de? Como corrigir tal erro? O que fazer em caso de...?"

Comment: Uma vez o autor resolveu seu problema, normalmente não dá muita bola pra mudanças mais radicais. Quando o título é pobre mesmo, a gente dá uma mão na roda ao deixá-lo mais descritivo e orgânico. . É essencial frisar que os sites Stack Exchange *não são fórums*, são sites de pergunta e resposta cujo modelo foi criado exatamente para não ter os problemas dos fóruns tradicionais (vide [blog Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com)).

Comment: Fazendo um search por [**`"title:titulo"`**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Atitulo): [Devo editar o título de uma pergunta a fim de torná-la mais objetiva?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2376/201)

Comment: Que fórum? [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/91)

Comment: "forum" é uma palavra desprezível na rede stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, o site está cheio de profissionais fazendo o que sabem melhor: respondendo perguntas interessantes e aproveitando para aumentar seu conhecimento durante esse processo. Sendo profissionais no que fazem, rapidamente aprendem a usar a ferramenta Stack Exchange, que intrinsecamente é über-profissional.

Normalmente, se a pessoa não é muito "chegada" à língua escrita, acaba melhorando bastante com o decorrer do tempo, nem que seja à força de edições alheias. A afinidade com o bom português não é privilégio de quem foi pra escola, o que mais existe é diplomado assassinando a gramática. Que eu saiba, basta ser um leitor assíduo que naturalmente a gramática correta se incorpora ao vocabulário e à escrita.

As ferramentas para administrar o site já estão todas à disposição, depende dos  [privilégios que já alcançou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Você pode praticar a edição de perguntas e respostas, e ser recompensado com 2 pontos por edição, até alcançar os 2 mil pontos quando adquire privilégio de editar sem supervisão alheia.
Inclusive, tem uma lista exclusiva para mostrar os usuários que participam ativamente da edição de posts: [***pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all)

Como dica para participação aqui no Meta: é importante conferir as discussões e tópicos anteriores sobre o tema que você quer levantar. Sugiro estudar as tags [edição](/questions/tagged/edi%c3%a7%c3%a3o), [formatação](/questions/tagged/formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e [edições-sugeridas](/questions/tagged/edi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-sugeridas); peça para organizar por "frequentes" ou "votos".